# Returned value of method asserted but MsTest still succeeding

Tags: c#, xamarin, exception, mstest

I have a method that returns a model object and that has no constructors. In three test cases a `HttpRequestException` is thrown. They still pass when asserting the model object, why is that so?

I am expecting the assert of the object to fail since it is null, or the test to fail since the assert is never made (exception throwed).

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace SolutionTest
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [DataTestMethod]
        [DataRow("Hello")]
        [DataRow("bad")]
        [DataRow("badcausing")]
        [DataRow("badcausingexception")]
        [DataRow("Goodbye")]
        public void method(string s)
        {
            string st = methodTested(s);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(st);
            Assert.IsTrue(st != null);
        }
        public string methodTested(string s)
        {
            if (s == "bad" || s == "badcausing" || s == "badcausingexception")
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("hey");
                throw new Exception();
            }
            return s;
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

When I uploaded this image I think I missed the red in "SolutionTest". Running without the exceptions gives me this. So I assume the half red means exceptions is throwed.

[image]

I was looking in the wrong place. Below is View > Test selected in the options. I had View > Pads > Unit Tests opened and was only looking at that. This is on Visual Studio for Mac 2017

[image]

Comment: Without seeing your code, I doubt anybody will by gifted enough to help you. Please post a [mcve] or at least your test.

Comment: Should it be a `DataTestMethod`? also why is the method body commented out?

Comment: I provided a more minimal example instead. I don't think it should pass as valid. It doesn't seem to matter if I use `[DataTestMethod]` or  `[TestMethod]`

Comment: Your example doesn't show the `class` containing `method(string)`.  Is that class marked as a `[TestClass]`?  If I paste your sample code into [this complete example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/testing/unit-testing-with-mstest) it behaves just as I would expect, the method fails or works depending on the DataRow used and Test Explorer or `dotnet test` reports the test failed.  That suggests your problem lies somewhere outside the code you have shown us so far.  Are you sure you are running the tests you think you are running, and are you sure they are succeeding?